# One-to-One and Nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My linear algebra textbook by Friedberg states the following Theorem:

> **Theorem:** Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, and let $T: V → W$ be linear. Then
>   $T$ is one-to-one if and only if $N(T) =$ {$0$}.

In one of the exercises, it asks whether the following is true or false:

> $T$ is one-to-one if and only if the only vector $x$ such that $T(x) = 0$ is
>   $x = 0$ .

The correct answer is that this statement is false. However, I don't understand how these two are not equivalent.

Comment: What pages of the book?  To me, it looks like you've mistyped something.

Comment: The theorem is on page 71, the question is on page 74 (question 1c). The answer key is page 572. (I'm using the PDF version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that exercise Friedberg assume $T$ is **just a function**, so this statement is false , for example, take $f(x)=x^2$ on $\Bbb{R}$. Here the only number $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ is $x=0$ but $f$ is not one-one!

So the mentioned result is true only when $T$ is **linear** (of course , Friedberg assumes $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional)